# get calendar pattern for a given locale

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

creating a form that needs user to input date in the pattern specific to the Locale (country).

Is it possible to get the pattern from a Java class whose input is Locale and output will be "yyyy/mm/dd" or "dd/mm/yyyy" ... 
Want to use this as a guidance on the form.

Comment: i think this issue has been beaten to death here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594519/how-do-i-get-localized-date-pattern-string. hope it helps.

Comment: most answers there talk about java 8. I am constrained to using java 7.

Comment: answer 2 there doesn't work for you ?