# Java localized date with custom format

Tags: java, java-time

I'm trying to support dates in different locales. At the moment all is working fine with the FormatStyle.SHORT.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(someDynamicLocale);
```

The problem is that the `year` field is only 2 digits long.
If I try to parse this string `"22/10/84"` in which century are we?

I can use the other formats (`MEDIUM`, `LONG`, `FULL`) but in all of this formats the month is a text instead of a number, and in my application is not applicable.

For this reason my dream is only to customize the SHORT format setting the length of the year field to 4 digits.

Is it possible? Can the `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try DateTimeFormatterBuilder, for example if you want the format "d.M.yyyy". you can use:

```
String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(
  FormatStyle.SHORT, null, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, 
  Locale.SPAIN);
```

here is a simmilar post [How do I get localized date pattern string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594519/how-do-i-get-localized-date-pattern-string)